# Get value of pivotfields for a particular cell

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table from ssas connection. Several pivotfields are being used in the table. For this example let's say they are Size, Color, and Location. My goal is to write some vba where I pass the cell range and get the value of the corresponding pivotfields.

For example, If I pass the cell range for `B6` I want to know that that cell is from location2 in color2 for size1. If I pass range `B8` I get location1, Color3, Size1 etc.

[image]

Here is what I can do so far. I can get the value of the formula for that cell. Here is the result for B6: `GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[myValues]",$A$1,"[d size].[size]","[d size].[size].&[Size1]","[d color].[color]","[d color].[color].&[Color2]","[d location].[location]","[d location].[location].&[location2]")` with this code:

```
Function xxx(ByVal xyz As Range) As Variant
  xxx = xyz.Formula
End Function
Sub blah()
  MsgBox (xxx(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D13")))
End Sub
```

I can also loop through the pivotfields and get their names, (but I don't know how to get their values) `[Measures].[myValues]`, `[d size].[size]` etc... with this code:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1)
    For i = 1 To .PivotFields.Count
        MsgBox .PivotFields(i).Name
    Next
End With
```

My question is now, how do I get the value of those pivotfields for a particular cell. I would like to be able to send `B6` and get back, or have access to: `location2`, `Color2`, `Size1`

**Edit:**

Getting closer... I can now loop through each field and get their names and values like this `[d size].[size]&[Size1]` etc, but now I want to be able to get just the value of `Size1` or `[Size1]`:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim iRange As Variant
  iRange = ActiveCell.Address
  FieldPicker (iRange)
End Sub

Function FieldPicker(targetCell As Variant) As Variant
  With Range(targetCell).PivotCell
      For i = 1 To .RowItems.Count
          MsgBox .RowItems(i).SourceName
      Next
  End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from RoryA's answer here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/332678-pivottable-problem.html

```
'Given a pivottable value cell and a category name, return the category value
'Note: you would need morte code to account for a "page" category 
Function PivotCategoryValue(rngInput As Range, fldName As String) As String

   Dim pc As PivotCell
   Dim pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
   Dim rv As String

   On Error Resume Next
   Set pc = rngInput.PivotCell
   On Error GoTo err_handle

   If pc Is Nothing Then
      rv = "Not a pivot cell"
   Else
      Select Case pc.PivotCellType
         Case xlPivotCellValue
            If pc.RowItems.Count Then
               For Each pi In pc.RowItems
                  If pi.Parent.Name = fldName Then
                    rv = pi.Value
                    GoTo done
                  End If
               Next pi
            End If
            If pc.ColumnItems.Count Then
               For Each pi In pc.ColumnItems
                  If pi.Parent.Name = fldName Then
                    rv = pi.Value
                    GoTo done
                  End If
               Next pi
            End If
         Case Else
            rv = "Not a pivot data cell"
      End Select
   End If
done:
   PivotCategoryValue = rv
Exit Function

err_handle:
   PivotCategoryValue = "Unknown error"
End Function
```

Comment: One bug in the code. The first `if` should have `strOut = "Not a pivot cell"`. This function will return `[d size].[size]:[d size].[size]&[Size1]` etc. So it is similar to some of my attempts. It does has all the error handling built in which is very nice, but I want to go one step further and get just the value of `Size1` or `[Size1]` etc.

Comment: I only posted this answer (which is a straight copy of RoryA's post) as a pointer to how to loop through the various category values (in `RowItems` and `ColumnItems`) associated with a particular "value" cell.  If what you want is a generic approach then you could pass in a field name and return a value from the code as soon as you find a field with the name you're looking for.

Comment: Hey that's a great feature +1. Now the hardest part that is in my original problem. From your update, I still get `[d size].[size]&[Size1]` does vba let me get just the end after that `&` without having to parse the string? That is really the value that I want to get back.

Comment: I guess I'm not following what it is you really want to do.  You can use the code I posted to get the value of a specific field associated with a specific value cell. I'm not following what you mean by "parse" the string or exactly where you get `[d size].[size]&[Size1]` from.

Comment: The code you posted returns `[d size].[size]&[Size1]` and I would like to have it return `Size1`. I already know that `Size1` comes from the `d size` dimension. Do you know if vba can give me just that value after the `&`?

Comment: I guess something completely different is going on on my machine versus yours.  My code (as it stands right now) returns only a single value, which is the value of the field name which was passed to the function along with the range containing the "value" pivot cell.

Comment: hmm... My pivot table is created through an Analysis Services connection to a MOLAP cube database. Perhaps the names of the pivot fields include the dimension names for a formal name?

Comment: No idea - for me with a regular pivot table that function just returns a single value.